Group labels in BoxWhiskerChart
data has dimensions {3,4,5}. The Mathematica code
C1 = BoxWhiskerChart[ 
  Table[data[[i, j]], {j, 4}, {i, 3}], 
  ChartLabels -> {"t=0.233", "t=0.707", "t=1.4", "t=5"}, 
  ChartLegends -> {"a=0", "a=0.35", "a=0.8"}] 

yields 3 color legends, and 12 (3 times 4) axis labels.

How should I rewrite the code to show each label only once, i.e. to show 4 labels? I would like to somehow group the charts into 4 groups of 3 charts, and label each group once, as in this question. I am not able to adapt the answer into a Table-syntax.

data={{{0.17101923`, 0.24051939`, 0.24981464`, 0.25860234`, 
0.30789173`}, {0.19082436`, 0.2424513`, 0.24981112`, 0.257887`, 
0.30328306`}, {0.188908`, 0.24204609`, 0.25018252`, 0.25827068`, 
0.31069845`}, {0.18706346`, 0.24101548`, 0.25001135`, 0.25900809`,
 0.3160004`}}, {{-.1, 0.20656927`, 0.25097252`, 0.28559238`, 
0.40514791`}, {0.1154707`, 0.23449509`, 0.24948783`, 0.26517419`, 
0.34329772`}, {0.1610397`, 0.23947387`, 0.249907`, 0.26014632`, 
0.32658658`}, {0.18894795`, 0.24099299`, 0.24999546`, 0.25899716`,
 0.32199998`}}, {{-.1`, 0.20439821`, 0.25047567`, 0.28367992`, 
0.40985144`}, {0.27130585`, 0.32491889`, 0.35551103`, 0.37728916`,
 0.46096039`}, {0.0836917`, 0.23260138`, 0.24920947`, 0.26630539`,
 0.35320561`}, {0.18880171`, 0.24096403`, 0.249975`, 0.25898308`, 
0.32299965`}}};


BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[data]   , ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"t=0.233", "t=0.707", "t=1.4", "t=5"},      Axis], Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, "LowerFence"]}  , ChartLegends -> {"a=0", "b=0.35", "c=0.8"}]  ?

@Syed Tyvm! BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[pi3Curr], ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"t=0.233", "t=0.707", "t=1.4", "t=5"}, Axis], Placed[{"", "", ""}, "LowerFence"]}, ChartLegends -> {"a=0", "a=0.35", "a=0.8"}] did exactly what I intended.

Would you like to write a quick answer, for closure?

Please write your own answer and include definition for pi3Curr. Thanks.

You can use the group and series syntax for ChartLables. Placed function is not needed.
BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[data]
 , ChartLabels -> {{"t=0.233", "t=0.707", "t=1.4", "t=5"}, None}
 , ChartLegends -> {"a=0", "a=0.35", "a=0.8"}]




Hope this helps.

This was the simple and direct kind of syntax I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Adapting @Syed's comment:
BoxWhiskerChart[
  Transpose[data],
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"t=0.233", "t=0.707", "t=1.4", "t=5"}, Axis],
Placed[{"", "", ""}, "LowerFence"]},
  ChartLegends -> {"a=0", "a=0.35", "a=0.8"}]

yields the chart with 4 axis-labelled groups, and 3 color-labelled legends.

